# XPath expressions for extracting information from AWIS (Alexa.com) XML data

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom, alexa-internet

I somehow can't manage to extract information from AWIS results (containing Alexa data).

I've a bunch of `XML` files containing AWIS data from which I want to extract information bits such as *Rank* and *PageViews for 3 month period*.

The two (colliding) namespaces are somehow confusing and my `XPath` expressions are not working as intended. (Even a simple `//aws:Rank/text()` is not working.)

It would be great if somebody could assist me to get going.

Currently, I am using `jdom` library, but wouldn't mind using something else. This is a tiny example that does not work as suspected:

```
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(file);
XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("//aws:Rank");
xpath.addNamespace("aws", "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11/");
Element rank = (Element) xpath.selectSingleNode(doc);
```

I'd prefer to use `javax.xml` though...

Here's an example of the `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
<aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
<aws:OperationRequest>
<aws:RequestId>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX</aws:RequestId>
</aws:OperationRequest>
<aws:UrlInfoResult>
<aws:Alexa>

  <aws:ContactInfo>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">ahparis.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:PhoneNumbers>
      <aws:PhoneNumber>+33 140289796</aws:PhoneNumber>
    </aws:PhoneNumbers>
    <aws:OwnerName>John Fay</aws:OwnerName>
    <aws:Email>hostmaster@superbregistrar.net</aws:Email>
    <aws:PhysicalAddress>
      <aws:Streets>
        <aws:Street>22 rue Saint Sauveur</aws:Street>
      </aws:Streets>
      <aws:City>Paris 75002,</aws:City>
      <aws:Country>FRANCE</aws:Country>
    </aws:PhysicalAddress>
    <aws:CompanyStockTicker/>
  </aws:ContactInfo>
  <aws:ContentData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">ahparis.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:SiteData>
      <aws:Title>Ah Paris</aws:Title>
      <aws:Description>Short term apartment rentals. Search engine, descriptions, photos, rates.</aws:Description>
      <aws:OnlineSince>26-Feb-2003</aws:OnlineSince>
    </aws:SiteData>
    <aws:Keywords>
      <aws:Keyword>Fran̤ais</aws:Keyword>
      <aws:Keyword>Ile-de-France</aws:Keyword>
    </aws:Keywords>
    <aws:OwnedDomains>
      <aws:OwnedDomain>
        <aws:Domain>paris-tournament.org</aws:Domain>
        <aws:Title>paris-tournament.org</aws:Title>
      </aws:OwnedDomain>
    </aws:OwnedDomains>
  </aws:ContentData>
  <aws:TrafficData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">ahparis.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:Rank>2547606</aws:Rank>
    <aws:RankByCountry/>
    <aws:RankByCity/>
    <aws:UsageStatistics>
      <aws:UsageStatistic>
        <aws:TimeRange>
          <aws:Months>3</aws:Months>
        </aws:TimeRange>
        <aws:Rank>
          <aws:Value>2547606</aws:Value>
          <aws:Delta>-658661</aws:Delta>
        </aws:Rank>
        <aws:Reach>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>2964984</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-152875</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.28</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-10.64%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
        </aws:Reach>
        <aws:PageViews>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.01</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+100%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>2143379</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-1628449</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerUser>
            <aws:Value>4.0</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+120%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerUser>
        </aws:PageViews>
      </aws:UsageStatistic>
      <aws:UsageStatistic>
        <aws:TimeRange>
          <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
        </aws:TimeRange>
        <aws:Rank>
          <aws:Value>1430628</aws:Value>
          <aws:Delta>-3224794</aws:Delta>
        </aws:Rank>
        <aws:Reach>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>1656655</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-5103474</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.5</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+500%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
        </aws:Reach>
        <aws:PageViews>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.02</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+100%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>1279227</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-859817</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerUser>
            <aws:Value>4</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-63.11%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerUser>
        </aws:PageViews>
      </aws:UsageStatistic>
      <aws:UsageStatistic>
        <aws:TimeRange>
          <aws:Days>7</aws:Days>
        </aws:TimeRange>
        <aws:Rank>
          <aws:Value>1927968</aws:Value>
          <aws:Delta>+757770</aws:Delta>
        </aws:Rank>
        <aws:Reach>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>2942088</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+1612570</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.3</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-64.64%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
        </aws:Reach>
        <aws:PageViews>
          <aws:PerMillion>
            <aws:Value>0.05</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+80%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerMillion>
          <aws:Rank>
            <aws:Value>708394</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>-413955</aws:Delta>
          </aws:Rank>
          <aws:PerUser>
            <aws:Value>10</aws:Value>
            <aws:Delta>+400%</aws:Delta>
          </aws:PerUser>
        </aws:PageViews>
      </aws:UsageStatistic>
    </aws:UsageStatistics>
    <aws:ContributingSubdomains>
      <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
        <aws:DataUrl>ahparis.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:TimeRange>
          <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
        </aws:TimeRange>
        <aws:Reach>
          <aws:Percentage>100.00%</aws:Percentage>
        </aws:Reach>
        <aws:PageViews>
          <aws:Percentage>100.00%</aws:Percentage>
          <aws:PerUser>4</aws:PerUser>
        </aws:PageViews>
      </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
    </aws:ContributingSubdomains>
  </aws:TrafficData>
</aws:Alexa>
</aws:UrlInfoResult>
<aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
<aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode>
</aws:ResponseStatus>
</aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

Comment: The XML contains the same namespace prefix for 2 different namespaces, is that valid?

Comment: That's part of my question ;-) That is the way it is retrieved from AWIS (an amazon service). Thus, I hope (and assume) that they know what they are doing...

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen yes, that's perfectly fine.  Prefix mappings are lexically scoped so at any point you just look up the tree for the nearest (ancestor-or-self) binding of the prefix in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a typo in the namespace URI - your code has

```
xpath.addNamespace("aws", "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11/");
```

(with a trailing slash) but the document has

```
xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"
```

(without the slash).

> I'd prefer to use javax.xml though...

Namespace handling is a real pain in `javax.xml.xpath`, because there's no default implementation of the `NamespaceContext` interface provided in the Java class library.  You have to either implement your own or use a third-party implementation (I usually go for the `SimpleNamespaceContext` from Spring).  If you're going to be doing a lot of XPath manipulation I'd suggest looking at [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net) (the HE version is free of charge) and use its [s9api](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xpath-api/s9api-xpath), as this supports the far more powerful version 2.0 of the XPath language.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to jdom2 and adjusted the namespace as you pointed out - and all is working now, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You hve a typo in your code. You have:

```
xpath.addNamespace("aws", "http://aws.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11/");
```

but you should have:

```
xpath.addNamespace("aws", "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11/");
```

(note the change from `aws` to `awis`).

Additionally, you should really be using JDOM 2.5, and the new XPath API that was introduced there. The JDOM 2.x versions have significantly better handling for namespaces, and generics on the resulting content. See [The changes in JDOM2.x XPath handling](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Feature-XPath-Upgrade)

Comment: Thanks, this happened during an edit as I tried adding both namespaces with different prefixes. As a side note and absolutely no offense intended, but I think your answer is rather a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using your input with xslt with the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:alex="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"
    xmlns:awis="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//awis:Rank/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and somehow I got an output of:

```
2547606
```

I suppose you have to register the namespaces in different prefixes, then use that in your xpath